# segment intersection in 3 dimension

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, intersection

We can solve the problem of segment intersection in 2D in O(nlgn) time. In this problem, we are given a set of line segments and we have to see if there is an intersection or not. Now her's a problem from CLRS.

Ques. Professor Charon has a set of n sticks, which are lying on top of each other in some
configuration. Each stick is specified by its endpoints, and each endpoint is an ordered triple giving its (x, y, z) coordinates. No stick is vertical. He wishes to pick up all the sticks, one at a time, subject to the condition that he may pick up a stick only if there is no other stick on top of it.
a. Give a procedure that takes two sticks a and b and reports whether a is above, below,
or unrelated to b.
b. Describe an efficient algorithm that determines whether it is possible to pick up all the sticks, and if so, provides a legal sequence of stick pickups to do so.

I find it is an extension of the segment intersection in 3D. In 2D, the sweep line moves in "y" and the array is sorted according to the "x" coordinate. I think in 3D, the sweep line should move in "z" dimension but m not sure how to sort now, since I have to take care of both "x" & "y".

If we somehow figure it out, I guess, if there is an intersection, then for part (b), its not possible to pick all the sticks.

Am I going in the right direction??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to use segment intersection in 2D to solve this problem.

Checking is one segment above the other is same as checking for there intersection in XY projection and if they intersect than compare Z coordinate of intersection point on each segment. E.g. for segments `a=((0,0,0), (2,2,2))` and `b=((0,2,3), (2,0,5))`, projection on XY is `((0,0), (2,2))` and `((0,2), (2,0))`. 2D intersection is `(1,1)`, and Z value in `(1,1)` for `a` is 1, and for `b` is 4. That means `b` is above `a`.

So, use segment intersection in 2D to find which segments are in relation. To find in which order to remove segments use [topological sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).

Comment: Segment intersection for part 1 is fine. But I am not able to understand the last statement ot the topological sort

Comment: Set of sticks with a relation is [partially ordered set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_order), which can be represented as directed graph. Find an order to pick up sticks is same as to find topological sort in that directed graph.

Comment: Does your example assume +Z points to up direction or away direction? The reason I, asking is because value of z defines above and below in your example.

Comment: Also why above or below test requires intersection in x-y plan? For example, if they didn't intersect in X-Y plan but if one had z greater than other, then shouldn't be they considered above and below anyway?

Comment: Description doesn't assume what direction is up. Just change order used in topological sorting. I assumed that sticks are removed vertically and because of that not intersecting sticks in XY don't block each other.